# Fuchsian model for the five punctured sphere

Tags: group-theory, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to find a discrete subgroup $\Lambda$ of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ such that 
$$\mathbb{H}/\Lambda \cong \Sigma_{0,5}$$
where $\Sigma_{0,5}$ is the five punctured sphere.

I know that, if $\Lambda=\Gamma(2)$, then $\mathbb{H}/\Lambda$ is the three punctured sphere $\Sigma_{0,3}$, this is proved by counting the orbits of $\Lambda$ on $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$. With this in mind, I've tried the same approach with different principal congruence subgroups $\Gamma(n)$, but none of them has 5 cusps as I require.

Maybe I'm missing something but I've run out of ideas. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

$\Gamma(n)$ is defined as the elements in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ congruent with the identity modulo $n$.

Comment: See [Diamond & Shurman](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf) p.81-83